# Where'd my "Effective Average Mhz" data go?

Tags: system-monitoring

I'm running Whatsup Gold for server monitoring.  All of a sudden during the middle of the day we stopped getting VM Effective Average Mhz data from one particular machine.  All sensors show as still up, and both the target and monitoring machines have been rebooted with no change.

All the services seem to be up.  SNMP and WMI are returning other data.  VMWare Tools is up.  I've been busy comparing services/settings against other VMs that are working fine and am coming up empty.

What else should I be looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to get this working that day (Friday).  Over the weekend we lost the rest of the WUG data logging.  Today, it all came back with a simple reboot.  Oddly, rebooting on Friday had made no change in status...